# How to efficiently compute the determinant of a matrix using elementary operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Need help to compute $\det A$ where
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}36&60&72&37\\43&71&78&34\\44&69&73&32\\30&50&65&38\end{matrix} \right)$$

How would one use elementary operations to calculate the determinant easily?

I know that $\det A=1$

Comment: If you care about the number of operations, here's a trick with 30 multiplications: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/968c30931d04a35c8b02d1bb386e690b45dc275c/Eigen/src/LU/Determinant.h?at=default#cl-75

Answer (score 5):

I suggest Gaussian Elimination till upper triangle form or further but keep track of the effect of each elementary.
[see here for elementary's effect on det](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Effect_of_Elementary_Row_Operations_on_Determinant)

Comment: or use softwares such as matlab or free sources like wolframalpha if dimension is too high

Comment: @RobertIsrael It might not be a waste of time if you are in exam.:)

Comment: Nobody in their right mind would ask for a $4 \times 4$ determinant with all distinct $2$-digit entries on an exam.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You cannot nullify this person's curiosity for a method that is of use by saying it is a waste of time. 4*4 determinants have appeared on my exam though not all 2-digit, but complicated enough. You are assuming too much, who are you to judge what is a waste of time for him anyway?

Comment: It's my homework. Then here isn't any fast solution?

Comment: I'm not claiming to be a judge, I'm just saying that for me it is a waste of time.  Those who like doing such things (or are forced to do them by sadistic instructors) are welcome to their own opinions.

Comment: @aiki93 if there is no specific requirement on which method, then I recommend method of minors see Steven's answer. If it is required to use elementary operations then use my method.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it without fractions.
You could start by subtracting row $2$ from row $3$ to get
$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 36&60&72&37\\ 43&71&78&34\\ 1&-2&-5&-2\\ 30&50&65&38
\end {array} \right]$$
Then subtract $36$, $43$, and $30$ times row $3$ from rows $1$, $2$ and $4$ respectively to get 
$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 0&132&252&109\\ 0&157&293&120\\ 1&-2&-5&-2\\ 0&110&215&
98\end {array} \right]$$
Expanding by minors in the first column, we just need one $3 \times 3$ determinant, which is $$132 \times 293 \times 98 + 252 \times 120 \times 110 + 109 \times 157 \times 215 - 132 \times 120 \times 215 - 252 \times 157 \times 98 - 109 \times 293 \times 110 = 1$$
I hope you're allowed to use a calculator for that...

Answer (score 0):

For a 4x4 determinant I would probably use the [method of minors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeterminantExpansionbyMinors.html): the 3x3 subdeterminants have a convenient(ish) mnemonic as a sum of products of diagonals and broken diagonals, with all the diagonals in one direction positive and all the diagonals in the other direction negative; this lets you compute the determinant of e.g. the bottom-right 3x3 as 71*73*38 + 78*32*50 + 34*69*65 - 34*73*50 - 71*32*65 - 78*69*38.  That's probably slightly less than a 5-minute calculation with pencil and paper and a 1-minute calculation with a calculator, which means you could find the overall determinant in maybe 5 minutes with calculator, 15-20 with pencil and paper.  Not blazingly fast, of course, but for me I suspect it'd be marginally faster than Gaussian Elimination, and the all-integer nature of it is (for me, at least) a minor plus.  Alternately, the subdeterminants can be computed by taking minors again; this cuts down slightly on the number of multiplications per subdeterminant(from 12 to 9) and gives a total of 40 multiplications to compute the 4x4 determinant.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what you mentioned is what I thought to be the standard way, do you know any other way?

Comment: @mezhang Well, there's the direct approach in terms of summing over all the permutations, but you're right that this is more or less the canonical brute-force method.  I'll add another method that actually works pretty well here...

Comment: Could you explain or show me a link to the summing over all permutations method? I don't know it.

Comment: @mezhang It's one of the definitions of the determinant; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants , for instance.